# Match regex only inside certain HTML tag

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to match certain string inside certain html tags.

```
<p>bla bla bla bla word bla</p> <!--- word bla bla ---!> <p>bla bla bla</p>
```

Only thing I came up was this:

```
p\>.+?\sword\s.+?\<\/p>
```

But it's not working properly - any advice?

Comment: What string do you want to match? Inside what tags?

Comment: Sorry, edited original post. Trying to match 'word'.

Comment: @user2594043 What language are you using? Also is it always in a comment?

Comment: Please edit to explain with words what you want to do (match `word`, inside which tags?) and don't let us guess what your non-working regex is supposed to do :) Also, what does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: <p>[^<]*(word)[^<]*</p>

Answer (score -1):

`<p>(?:.*?)(word)(?:.*?)<\/p>`

http://regex101.com/r/bR3uV6

Comment: he wants to match only the string `word`. You stored it into a group. But itsn't op wants.